# Joining Query with Multiple Tables Based on Values

Tags: php, mysql

Supposed I have a table `posts` like below:

```
|    id    |     type     |     ref_id     |
-----------+--------------+ ---------------
|    1     |      1       |      1         |
|    2     |      1       |      2         |
|    3     |      3       |      3         |
|    4     |      1       |      4         |
|    5     |      2       |      5         |
|    6     |      3       |      6         |
```

The type field is to join with other tables, so for example 1=blogs, 2=reviews, 3=photos, and each of them have respective fields, while ref_id is the ID of the blog/review/photo.

What i want to do is to show all latest posts (order by id DESC), while joining with all other tables based on the value of the type, but I want to do it with one query if possible. My no-good query is below:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
LEFT JOIN blogs ON posts.ref_id = blogs.ID AND posts.type = 1
LEFT JOIN reviews ON posts.ref_id = reviews.ID AND posts.type = 2
LEFT JOIN photos ON posts.ref_id = photos.ID AND posts.type = 3
ORDER BY posts.id DESC
```

The query doesn't result in anything. Another alternative is to loop the SELECT * FROM posts query and do another query based on the type, but if possible, I'd like to do it in 1 go.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you need to bracket the ON clause?

Comment: I see sevaral errors. First I don't see the need for the AND. You can put all in a WHERE clasuole. Second, you use posts.type_id which doesn't exist in your table.

Comment: @BenjieGillam : what do you mean? I don't think that matters?

AurelioDeRosa : I've edited my question, it's a typo. What do you mean on WHERE clause? I'm not looking to target a certain ref_id, I want to get all posts, I just need to find a way to connect ref_id to the correct table based on the type.

Comment: Do you want **all** posts? Or the **latest** post?

Comment: @ypercube : it doesn't really matter. Latest is basically all posts ordered by DESC and limited to a certain number, not the point of my question

Answer (score 0):

To see why your query does not return anything, consider moving the " AND posts.type = " from JOIN to WHERE clause. It will be:

```
select * from posts ... where type=1 and type=2 and type=3
```

Obviously, it will return no results. I know it is not the answer to your question, but I would consider a small change in your table definitions:

(table name: fields)

```
posts: id
blogs: id, post_id
reviews: id, post_id
photos: id, post_id
```

In this case you will be able to construct simpler and more traditional queries:

```
select * from posts
    left join blogs on blogs.post_id = posts.id
    left join reviews on reviews.post_id = posts.id 
    left join photos on photos.post_id = posts.id
```

Comment: nice idea, but i have to think of the whole picture first before trying your suggestion because the actual case is quite complex

Comment: i've tried your idea, but it doesn't work. The result of the query only displays the last joined table

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this:

```
(   SELECT posts.*, blogs.*  
    FROM posts
      JOIN blogs 
        ON  posts.ref_id = blogs.ID 
        AND posts.type = 1
UNION ALL
    SELECT posts.*, reviews.* 
    FROM posts
      JOIN reviews 
        ON  posts.ref_id = reviews.ID 
        AND posts.type = 2
UNION ALL
    SELECT posts.*, photos.* 
    FROM posts
      JOIN photos 
        ON  posts.ref_id = photos.ID 
        AND posts.type = 3
)
ORDER BY posts.id DESC
```